# A doubt about derivative of a function at certain point

Tags: calculus

This may sound stupid but I am really confused.

Let's assume $z=g(x)$ and $y=f(x)$. The derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ is $f'(x)$. Suppose $f'(x^*)=0$. So, $z$ at $x^{*}$ is $g(x^{*})$.

Now let's compute ${\partial z\over\partial y}$,

$${\partial z\over\partial y}=g'(x){\partial x\over\partial y}$$

$${\partial z\over\partial y}=g'(x)\frac{1}{\partial y\over\partial x}$$

So, ${\partial z\over\partial y}$ is undefined at $x^*$. That means $z$ is undefined at $x^*$ but previously we saw that $z$ at $x^{*}$ is $g(x^{*})$. What is the justification?

Comment: I don't understand: why do you think $\;z\;$ is a function of $\;y\;$ ? If it isn't then simply $\;\cfrac{dz}{dy}=0\;$ ...And even if this isn't a problem, why the derivative $\;z'_y\;$ not existing at $\;x^*\;$ would imply $\;z\;$ isn't defined there?

Comment: I thought we can write $z=g(f^{-1}(y))$. But we know that $z$ is defined at $x^*$

Comment: You can write $z=g(f^{-1}(y))$ but only when $f$ is invertible. One sufficient condition for the same is that $f'(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Also note that the derivative $dz/dy$ may exist even if $dy/dx=0$. Thus if $z=x^{6},y=x^{3}$ then $z=y^{2}$ and $dz/dy=0$at $y=0$ even though $dy/dx=0$ at $x=y=0$.

Comment: Also why do you use the symbol $\partial$ which is normally needed for partial derivatives?

Comment: @Paramanand Singh, yes it should be $dy$ instead of $\partial{y}$. Regarding your first comment, consider $z=x^3,y=x^2$. Then we can write $z=y^{3/2}$ but $f'(x)=0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: The condition $f'(x) \neq 0$ is sufficient but not necessary.  The right example is given in my previous comment. Your example of $z=y^{3/2}$ has an issue because if $x<0$ then $y>0,z<0$ but $z=y^{3/2}$ implies that both $y, z$ are non-negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have discovered
the hard part
of proving the
chain rule
for the derivative
of a composite function.

If
$h(x) = f(g(x))$,
the chain rule states that
$h'(x) = g'(x)f'(g(x))$.

The proof of this is easy
at any $x$ such that
$g'(x) \ne 0$.

However,
if $g'(x) = 0$,
the proof is more difficult,
and requires careful reasoning.

So,
congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

> So, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ is undefined at $x^*$. That means $z$ is undefined at $x^*$ but previously we saw that $z$ at $x^{*}$ is $g(x^{*})$. What is the justification?

As noted in the comments by Paramanand Singh, there are technical issues surrounding the possibility of inverting $f$ to obtain $z = g(f^{-1}(y))$ from $z = g(x)$ and $y = f(x)$.

Even if inverting $f$ is possible, however, just because a function's *derivative* is undefined at a point does not mean the function *value* is undefined.

For example, take $z = g(x) = x$ and $y = f(x) = x^{3}$ (and $x^{*} = 0$), so that $z = g(f^{-1}(y)) = y^{1/3}$.